# Can't reference a dynamically added jQuery Mobile element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm adding a collapsible button and a simple `<a>` element to my main html.
The code is as follows:

```
var elements = "";

$('.button').bind('tap', function() {
    elements += "<div class='my_clicker' data-role='collapsible'><h4>heading1</h4><h4>heading2</h4></div>";
    elements += "<a href='#' class='my_clicker'>Click me!</a>";
    $(".button_container").html(elements).trigger('create');
};

$(document.body).on('tap', '.my_clicker' ,function(){
    playAudio('success');
});
```

When I click the `<a>` element the audio works fine so it seems like everything works except for the fact that '.my_clicker' doesn't reference my collapsible element, i.e. can't find it. So it seems like the regular jQuery referencing works but the jQuery Mobile element is somehow different and can't be easily referenced. Even when I use 'div' instead of '.my_clicker' in my `$(document.body).on()` function still all the div elements make a sound but my collapsible button does not. (I've also tried 'a' and 'h4' instead of '.my_clicker')

While inspecting my html elements in the browser, when I click on the collapsible element the expression **::before** is highlighted instead of the `<div>` I've added.

**EDIT:** Turns out the above code actually works on my tablet (as apk) despite not working in the browser! Still, would be nice to know how to make it work in the browser since jQuery Mobile can be used for web apps too.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using live() instead of on() ? It works for dynamically created elements.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: this could also be useful. http://www.codedisqus.com/0izVPePPWU/dynamically-create-ids-for-jquery-mobile-elements-then-reference-them.html